# How can I use GitHub CLI to include search queries with spaces?

Tags: search, spaces, github-cli, github-issues

I'm trying to use [GihHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/) to perform searches on my issues list and my search needs to be able to include spaces.

My search in GitHub would look like this:
`label:"Pod 1"`
But I don't know how to construct the command line. I have tried:

```
gh issue list --search label:"Pod 1"
```

and

```
gh issue list --search "label:Pod\ 1"
```

I could just use
`gh issue list --label "pod 1"` but I want to be able to use an "or" condition and include multiple labels at once and I want use `--search` since it is more robust than just `--label`.